# How can I prevent duplicated output from incoming webhooks in Slack?

Tags: cloudflare, slack-api

We have set up HealthChecks in Cloudflare that use Slack's webhooks for informing our teams in a Slack workspaces about changes of some server's health conditions.

Initially, this went fine, but then, time after time, the different Cloudflare notifications started to create double output in our respective workspaces.

Cloudflare's dev were able to proof that they only call the webhook api once per message, but nevertheless, they appear immediately twice, as if the same message would be duplicated and then sent to the channel.

And so the fact that deleting the notification on the Cloudflare- side and creating a new one did not change the phenomenon came to no surprise.

Deleting the webhook for the Slack workspace and creating a new one and assinging it to the notifications in Cloudflare helps, though. But only for a limited undetermined time.

Does anyone have experience with this phenomenon and can tell me why this is and/or how I can prevent the Cloudflare notifications from appearing twice each in our Slack workspaces?

Comment: Any luck with the issue? I am facing something very similar with a custom Powershell script I use to send messages to a Slack channel using a webhook

Comment: The only way that seemed to work for me was sending my messages one after the other instead of batching them by packs of 50 (Slack limitation). I've tried to artificially wait between two batches => same result. I tried to minimize the wait between two requests to the webhook => same result. I print the JSON that is being sent to the webhook, and there is definitely no duplicate and I don't call the function twice for a same batch. I also tried to send an empty message between batches to shake Slack up, no effect.

Comment: I'm using the Block Kit to layout my messages. Slack has a hard limit of 50 blocks.
Because I have quite some content to send, I was building my messages with 50 blocks.
My messages stopped being sent twice when I limited my JSON body to have 16 blocks or less. **Some** messages with 17+ blocks were being sent twice.
This is nonsense, but that will do it for now.

Comment: Note that I face the same issue with a bot API token instead of a webhook 